# error: expected ‘)’ before ‘:’ token

Tags: c, popen

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    FILE *in;
    extern FILE *popen();
    char buff[512];
    char buff2[1024];

    snprintf(buff2, 1024, "ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | awk '{for(i=0;i<5;i++) sub(":","-",$5); print $5}'");
    if(!(in = popen(buff2, "r")))
    {

            exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), in)!=NULL){
            printf("%s", buff);
    }
    pclose(in);

    return 0;
}
```

I have no idea why I am getting this error, can some one help me please.

Comment: Please indicate the exact line, and reformat your post. It is not all formatted as Code atm.

Comment: Instead of `extern FILE *popen();`, include the right header. Then the compiler will check arguments for you, possibly diagnosing further errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at your use of open/close double quotes on this line:

```
    snprintf(buff2, 1024, "ifconfig eth0 | grep HWaddr | awk '{for(i=0;i<5;i++) sub(":","-",$5); print $5}'");
```

You are closing the double quotes right before the :.  Try escaping the double-quotes within the string with \".

Comment: Thank you so much RobP, sorry for being stupid. Appreciate your help.

Comment: @Raghu you should avoid saying thank you in comments, instead, you can mark the answer or give it point by two arrows. You can do the same thing about the comments

Comment: @emab: I don't see anything wrong with saying thank you, but you're right you should do those other things too at least.

Comment: @Raghu would you mind accepting the answer so this doesn't showing unanswered? thx!

Answer (score 0):

Try escaping your quotation marks within your string.